# What does "à" mean in this sentence?

Tags: prépositions

In the following sentence:

> Les personnes à la retraite

What is the meaning of "à" in the above sentence?

And, does the above sentence mean: "The people want to retire"?

Answer (score 3):

This means

> **Retired** people

Actually, **to retire** can be translated to **partir à la retraite** in french. But **à** has no direct translation.

Answer (score 2):

It means *retired people*, as @Spadon wrote.

It may help you to think of ***people in retirement*** as an English phrase that more closely follows the French structure here, even though it is more common to refer to such people as simply *retired*.

*La retraite* is essentially *retirement* in English.